# Blurry background sprite, other sprites fine

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

Why is the background blurry, but all the other sprites fine?

[image: Background sprite blurred]

The background sprite has the same settings as the others. It's on the same Z position (0). It happened after I made some changes to the original image, just deleting some colours on it, not changing it's dimensions. It's coming from a sprite sheet of 11 images. All the images are blurred in the same way

[image: Sprite improt settings]

**Details**

- The camera is set *orthographic*.
- The camera size is set to 95.
- The camera is at [0,0,-10].
- The background sprite is at [0,0,0].
- The sprites are all at Z=0;
- The sprite is W: 256, H: 174.
- Anti-aliasing is disabled in the project.

Comment: Have you tried different compression options at the bottom there? DXT1 is notoriously cruel to vector art. What does it look like if you reimport it as truecolor?

Comment: @DMGregory I've tried all the options in the _Format_ drop down in the _Default_ box.  No change there.  It was rendering fine with DX1.  After redoing the sprite sheet it went blurry despite it being exactly the same dimensions and number of sprites and format (PNG)..

Comment: @DMGregory I added some details.

Comment: Can you show us the source asset file?

Comment: @DMGregory Here it is.  https://i.imgur.com/gd3Ewhr.png There are 11 sprites, equally sized.  It should be width:  `4816`, height:  `174`.

Comment: @DMGregory Upping the _Max Size_ to `4096` makes it render correctly.  I hadn't changed that value before now though.

Comment: Sounds like you made your texture too wide, and Unity was forced to downsample it to fit in the max width set in the import settings. When in doubt, try to work in power-of-two sizes to avoid unwanted adjustments to your image assets.

Comment: @DMGregory Is texture size different to sprite size?